# aggregating multiple fields from documents in separate collections using MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, non-relational-database

I used below code to display result of two fields of separate collections: InfoMovie and Rate, having MID as common field between them. I want a resultset that displays "Actors" from collection "InfoMovie" and "remark" from collection "Rate" into one resltset using Mongodb. But when i execute below code, it just displays the list of "remark" but it doesnt show the remarked actors name. [Note: all the actors in the collection aren't remarked.Few of them are remark. We have to display the remarked actor's name only.] 
I would be very thankful if anyone could solve this. Thank you in advance! :)

```
db.InfoMovie.aggregate([
 {
    $lookup: 
    { 
        from:"Rate",
        localField:"MID", 
        foreignField:"MID", 
        as:"ActorsRating"
    }
},
    {
        $project:{"Remark":1,"Actors":1}
    }
])
```

Below are the sample documents:
sample document of collection infoMovie :

```
{
    "MID":"1",
    "MovieName":"Iron man",
    "Actors":"RDJ",
    "RDate":"2008",
    "Country":"USA",
}, 

{
    "MovieID":"2",
    "MovieName":"Dark Knight",
    "Actors":"Christian Bail",
    "RDate":"2007",
    "Country":"USA",
}
```

The mongod version that i am using is 3.4.7. Thank You !

sample document of collection Rate:

```
{
    "MID":1,
    "ReviewedBy":"John",
    "Rate":4,
    "Date":"10/04/2013",
    "remark":"The best Movie ever!",
},
{
    "MID":2,
    "ReviewedBy":"William",
    "Rate":8,
    "Date":"19/06/2014",
}
```

Comment: project stage should be like this `$project:{"Remark":"$ActorsRating","Actors":1}`

Comment: But it also gives the result of the movies that aren't remarked. How can we not display those that aren't remarked? Thanks anyway.

Comment: Ok so can you post the sample document from both the collections and mention you mongodb version as well

Comment: Hello Sir! I have added the codes of documents. Could you please go through it!

Comment: We can identify that with the help of attribute "remark" in collection "rate". Collection "Rate" consists of few of the movies names from Collection "InfoMovie" and remark column contains comments to the movies that are remarked and which are not. Is it possible to display the actors name from InfoMovie and remark from Rate as a resultset?  Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation

You need to use [**`$filter`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) aggregation to filter out the documents where `Remark` is equal to undefined.

```
db.InfoMovie.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": { 
    "from":"Rate",
    "localField":"MID", 
    "foreignField":"MID", 
    "as":"ActorsRating"
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "Actors": 1,
    "Remark": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": "$ActorsRating",
        "as": "ac",
        "cond": { "$ne": ["$$ac.remark", undefined] }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Comment: @Rocky, for performance reasons it would be a good idea to upgrade to v3.6 or higher because you can then leverage an index on your "remark" field and move the `$match` stage into the `$lookup` pipeline.

Comment: @dnickless yes but the OP is not on 3.6.

Comment: Yes, no worries, that's why I wrote that it would be good if he could upgrade.

Comment: Then I think you should have commented on question :)